# Does a water heater have to be completely full for the water to heat?

Tags: water-heater

We installed a new water heater and it is not hot. We think it is full. Does a water heater have to be completely full for the water to heat? We think we may possibly have a leak in the hot water pipes going to the faucets. Could that stop a water heater from heating the water?

Comment: When did you replace it? Is it gas or electric? If it is electric did you fill the tank full before you turned on the power? What temperature did you set the water heater at? How big is the house?

Comment: @WarLoki  It was installed today. It's electric. But my main question is if I have a leak somewhere in the hot water outlet pipe that takes the water from the water heater to the faucets, would that stop the water heater from heating. I know water comes from the top of the tank first and as it is taken out it refills. But if it never filled completely in the first place cause of the leak then the top heating element has not heated the water. Just wanted to know if a leak could cause this.

Comment: If you do have a leak on the hot water side, the water heater it will never have a chance to catch up. But first things first, have you noticed an increase in your electric and your water bill. If the answer is yes to both then you may have a leak. If no you may have a bad(new) water heater.

Comment: @WarLoki No increase in water bill, this leak has just happened in the last few days. Last Wednesday I turned on hot water and no hot water so we figured the water heater was bad. So we bought a new one and installed it. We thought it was full so we plugged it in but still no hot water. Had a plumber come look at it and he was saying sounded like water running but he also thought it was a defective heater so we took it back and got another one. Still no hot water on this one either. This is why I am thinking if there is a leak then the water heater is not filling enough to heat the water.

Answer (score 4):

Any leak large enough to stop the water from filling the heater tank would have to be so large as to basically be an open ended line. It would be impossible not to notice the flooding caused by a leak this large. A smaller leak would not stop the heater from filling and operating and you would have some hot/warm water delivery. I am not saying you **don't** have a leak, but I strongly suspect an electrical issue. It could be related to power supply, or it could be related to damage caused by improper heater installation or operation. Call a *reputable professional* plumber please.